# Send email with Mailgun in angular

Tags: angularjs, email, http, mailgun, unauthorized

This is my code:

```
function sendEmail(){
    return $http.post('https://api:<MY SECRET API KEY>@api.mailgun.net/v3/<DOMAIN>/messages', {
                from: "hello@<DOMAIN>",
                to: 'test@mail.com',
                subject: "Subject text",
                text: "Body text"
            }).then(function(data){
                return data;
            }, function(error){
                //manage error
            })
        }
```

This is giving me a 401 Unauthorized error

**UPDATE:**

I have find this post where it's fixed --> [Mailgun + AngularJS + Auhtentication for http post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36815470/mailgun-angularjs-auhtentication-for-http-post-request)

In my case, multipart is not needed.

Comment: I have find this post where it's fixed --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36815470/mailgun-angularjs-auhtentication-for-http-post-request

Answer (score 0):

Looks like to use their API you need to get authenticated by the server first.

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-intro.html#authentication. It looked like you need to set the API key in the URL.

Comment: Mmm, I tried this too but does not work, continues giving me a 401 Unauthorized. Do I need to get authenticated by server?

Comment: You need to be using basic auth. See this: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/05/26/AngularJS-Basic-HTTP-Authentication-Example.aspx